# How can I make Scratch execute scripts

Tags: code

I want to use the scratch text editor to execute python3 scripts. 
Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: You want the scripts and debugging output to appear in a terminal in Scratch?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Open Scratch
2. Open Preferences
3. Switch to Extensions
4. Terminal (Close Preferences)
5. Click new Terminal icon in headerbar.
6. Execute Python in attached Terminal.

[image: Enabling Terminal in Scratch]
[image: Terminal in Scratch]

Comment: Notice that Scratch is not "executing" anything, nor could it since it's a text editor. This attaches a terminal to it, but it's not different from simply running your script in an open instance of Terminal.